# Set runtime parameter value for GOGC during compile time?

Tags: go

I was wondering if there was a way to set GOGC in my init() function itself ? 
I used SetGCPercent(300), but wasn't sure if that meant that GOGC=300 or if it meant that it can go upto 300.

Thanks

Comment: calling `SetGCPercent`  in your `init` is how you would set it in your code. Setting `SetGCPercent` is equivalent to setting `GOGC`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure, since the exact wording in the explanation was target percentage. This helps!

Comment: Also, can i change the value of GOGC during program execution ? Will I have to restart my process to take the values of GOGC ?